# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: ftp

I desperately want to open this web but it keep asking me to Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I don't even know anything about it. I tried to follow other suggestions but kept failing.

Comment: What are you using? Are you on xampp?

Comment: Well it's self explanatory, you need username of database and the correspondent passwod

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you're working with a database, and you haven't set a password before, then there shouldn't be any password. Sometimes the database sets the password automatically to "NO", meaning there is no password. Which means in your config file you should change...

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "NO",
```

to

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "",
```